# Validation Opencart

Tags: php, validation, opencart

i want to add php phone number validation in opencart code sample is given below

```
    if(!filter_var($customer_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $errors[$pos++] = 'Email is not valid.';
        }

        if($customer_mobile=='') {
            $errors[$pos++] = 'Please enter your Mobile.';
        } /*elseif (strlen($customer_mobile) < 11 || !is_numeric($this->request->post['cell_number'])){
            $errors[$pos++] = 'Mobile number should be 7 digits.';
        }*/
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@Tayyab Gulsher Vohra....

I am  also facing this problem.I concluded myself and made it.
follow the instruction.,
The opencart is a **MVC structure** platform,so you need to know about Controller , Model and view ,Here Controller is first initialization telephone number in `index()`function

```
if (isset($this->request->post['telephone'])) {
            $this->data['telephone'] = $this->request->post['telephone'];
        } else {
            $this->data['telephone'] = $this->customer->getTelephone();
        }
```

further, telephone number must be valid using this method.,

```
 function validate()
        if( !preg_match("/^([1]-)?[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/i", $this->request->post['telephone']) ) {
                    $this->error['telephone'] = $this->language->get('error_telephone');
                }
```

then you should be initialized **telephone number** value in language file.

Comment: Your code is right u can define this support which format like (91)-112-122-1252 ?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have 2 options, validate or filter.
Because phone numbers are different in length and characters, what I would suggest is that you just filter

```
FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT
```

Remove all characters except digits, plus and minus sign.

for more info:
[Filters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php)

**EXAMPLE**:

```
<?php echo filter_var("Home: +1 (123) 456-7890 @ John", FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sanitizer functions are not really ready for validation of phone numbers and I would probably use a regex leaving ( ) + - : e and numbers in as this allows for most variations of international numbers and extensions.