# Phone Number Validation in opencart 2.0.3.1

Tags: opencart2.x

I'm trying to validate phone number in my opencart 2.0.3.1  installation.

I follow this [validation-opencart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207061/validation-opencart) but I have no luck.

Is there any tutorial for this?

Comment: I can help you out. What sort of validation do you like? :)

Comment: What is the controller where you want to validate the phone number?

Comment: The validation I want is if there any letters in the telephone number. I want the user to fill up  the form with numbers only.

Comment: That is easy. You will have to check for it in the validation process of opencart. The function is written in controller. You will have to add your chunk of code. :)